# Get the value of a clicked link through Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to fetch the value of a clicked link but i am getting undefined.
Please find the code that i have been trying:

```
<table id="tableData" style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <tr> 
            <td><a onClick="changeValue();">Apple</a> </td>
            <td>23-May-2016</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '#tableData td a', function () {
    alert($(this).parent().attr('value'));
});
```

Now when i click on the `Apple` link I should get the value `Apple` but what I get is `undefined`. Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to retrieve the `text()` of the `a`, not the `value` attribute of the parent. Try this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#tableData td a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableData" style="width: 100%;">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Apple</a></td>
    <td>23-May-2016</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note that I also fixed some issues in your HTML, namely the redundant `tr` and `onclick` attribute, and added a `href` to make it valid.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You could Retrieve That Particular Clicked Item On Anchor With .text() Then Its Works. Try It Once

```js
$(document).on('click', '#tableData td a', function() {
  var value = $(this).text();
  alert(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableData" style="width: 100%;">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Apple</a></td>
    <td>23-May-2016</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">Nokia</a></td>
    <td>23-May-2016</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">SamSung</a></td>
    <td>23-May-2016</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What's the point of adding this answer when it's identical to one already posted?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of binding jquery click you can even pass this in your function as a param and get the value from this parameter.